# How to reverse the youTube feed Json in reverse order in android?

Tags: android

I have parsed the json array of youtube uploads and viewed in listview everything is working perfect except the order. The last update of youtube is in the end of listview not in the top. How can ı reverse the json array so that ı list the latest update on the top.
    Thanks for any help.

Comment: instead of reversing json try to reverse listview adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Collections;
Collections.reverse(arrayList);
```

Comment: Thanks Wesley. you really save my day :)